# AngularJS Remove Substring from String in an expression {{}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this markup in my angularJS mark up

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url('{{item.mageURL}}')"></div>
```

The `{{item.mageURL}}` expression producing a string like:

> http://example.com/photos/68678/stamp

I would like to change it to:

> http://example.com/photos/68678

So far, without success, I've tried...

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url('{{item.mageURL.str.substring( 0, str.indexOf( 'stamp' ) )}}')"></div>
```

But it just returns an empty string.

Any idea how I can do this in AngularJS

Comment: I would suggest you to keep this kind of logic in your controller, and keep templates easier to read. Cheers.

Comment: I would suggest you **not** dirty up your controllers and instead either fix what your issue is (which it looks like you have a few solutions regarding the String APIs) OR utilize filters instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply `substring` method to `item.mageURL.str` string.

```
'{{item.mageURL.str.substring( 0, item.mageURL.str.indexOf( '/stamp' ) )}}'
```

Another method is to use `split` method.

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url('{{item.mageURL.str.split('/stamp')[0]}}')"></div>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.item={
      "mageURL":{
            "str":'http://example.com/photos/68678/stamp'
        }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url('{{item.mageURL}}')"></div>
    {{item.mageURL.str.split('/stamp')[0]}}<br>
    {{item.mageURL.str.substring( 0, item.mageURL.str.indexOf( '/stamp' ) )}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this best, if it works.  Keep your controllers simple and UX driven.  Keep logic like this either in your templates or use a filter.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense.  Damn copy & past with `str`

Answer (score 1):

please use 'ng-style' https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' +  item.mageURL.str.substring( 0, item.mageURL.str.indexOf( 'stamp' ) )+')'}"

```
<div class="photo" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' +  item.mageURL.str.substring( 0, item.mageURL.str.indexOf( 'stamp' ) )+')'}"></div>
```

Comment: why is `ng-style` better in this case?

Comment: in general performance is better with ng-style as it adds a watch on the model and will update the view only if the model has changed, in this case item.mageurl.str. When you use style it will execute everytime.

Comment: interesting, it is wrapped in a `ng-repeat` so I think it has a watch on it already?

Comment: the ng-repeat watch triggers when count of the array / properties changes. ng-style has its own watch.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be much better to create a tiny directive for this purpose, like this

```
app.directive('bgImg', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.css('background-image', someTransformFn(attrs.bgImg));
  }
})
```

Long JS-expressions in the templates are the real pain, in comparison with this:

```
<div bg-img="{{vm.someImg}}">
```